# iPhone inter-app URL handling: Can it be done in the background?

Tags: iphone, url, background

I'm working on passing a couple simple things (like timestamps and settings) between apps installed on one iPhone, and I was wondering if there's any way to use inter-app URL handling in the background.  The goal would be to pass a URL to another app without having it open, or even to simply have the receiving app detect when something else checks for the ability to open that URL.

Any chance that (or something similar) is possible in an app-store-friendly way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think thus is possible, but you could achieve this by setting up a webservice that "communicates" between the individual apps.

Comment: Thanks - I definitely thought about that, but doesn't work when connectivity is scarce.  Oh well.